# swift4 realm model - override description (java toString() equivalent)

Tags: ios, model, realm, overriding, swift4

I have a problem. I am trying to override description method to print reference values as I want. I read that this is equivalent to Java toString() method (I am new to swift)

The problem is that, it is not working and I can't find any solution for that. I did it exactly as in examples.. What did I do wrong?

Here's my code:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

@objcMembers class Patient: Object{

    //toString()
    override var description: String{
        return "Patient: Ref nr: \(self.referenceNumber), First name: \(self.firstName), Surname: \(self.surname) Email:  \(self.email)"
    }

    var patientId:Int{
        return self.patientId
    }
    dynamic var referenceNumber: String = ""
    dynamic var firstName:String = ""
    dynamic var surname:String = ""
    dynamic var email:String = ""

    convenience init(referenceNumber:String, firstName:String, surname:String, email:String) {
        self.init()
        self.referenceNumber = referenceNumber
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.surname = surname
        self.email = email
    }
```

Now, whenever I try to print that: (I posted more code in case smith wrong is earlier than printing)

```
var patient: Results<Patient>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    let realm = RealmService.shared.realm
    let patient = realm.objects(Patient.self) //tocheck: can I get only one element from Realm and set to store only 1 element?

    //HERE IT GOES WRONG
    print(patient) //case 1
    print(patient.description) //case 2
}
```

It prints in the console that: (in both cases the same)

```
Results<Patient> <0x7fccaaf03b90> (
    [0] Patient {
        referenceNumber = 231321;
        firstName = James;
        surname = Rodriguez;
        email = jr@lalalla.pl;
    }
)
```

WHY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation for the String description in your object is right. It is a correct [Computed Property](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259). As such, Realm [will ignore it](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#ignoring-properties) for storage, but it is still available for you to use it.

When you're invoking `let patient = realm.objects(Patient.self)` the Realm is giving you a `Results<Patient>` object. Think of it as an Array of `Patient` objects. So, for example if you're looking for the description of the first element it is possible to get it as you would do it in an Array:

```
if let firstPatient = realm.objects(Patient.self).first {
    print(firstPatient.description)
}
```

For a very good reference on this subject check out the [Realm docs for Results](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html).

Comment: Thanks for help and the explanation - that was the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying print an array. Try patient[0].description (patient is not the best name, maybe patients?).